# Display message after form submit with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to show the message what I type for submitting after clicking submit button with javascript. 
I wonder I have to use alert or modal for it with javascript. I just want to use Javascript instead of JQuery or Ajax.

```
<body>

<form action="index.html" method="POST">
 <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
 <input type="text" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">
 <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
 <input type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name">
 <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like the following:

```js
let form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Form Submitted!");
});
```

```html
<form action="index.html" method="POST">
  <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" />
  <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following code will help.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("form");

form.onsubmit = function(){
let inputs = Object.fromEntries([...form.children].filter(e=>e.localName=="input"&&e.placeholder).map(e=>[e.placeholder,e.value]));

for(key in inputs) alert(key+": "+inputs[key]);
}
```

```html
<body>

<form id="form" action="index.html" method="POST"> <!--i've added an id -->
 <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
 <input type="text" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">
 <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
 <input type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name">
 <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
```